# Run Visual Studio template Azure AD authenticated ASP.NET Core MVC application in Docker

Tags: docker, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an AzureAD authenticated ASP.NET Core MVC application using the Visual Studio template.  For testing I would like to run the application in my local Docker instance.

After using the Visual Studio generated Docker File, however, I get the following error:

```
Correlation failed.
```

[image: errorMessage]

**DockerFile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyApp/MyApp.csproj", "MyApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp/MyApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApp"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

The port is bound as follows:

```
8080:80
```

I have already set the callback URL in AzureAD as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/signin-oidc
```

**UPDATE**

I found some articles that advised adding the following:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

However this generates a new error:

```
Exception: Unable to unprotect the message.State.
Unknown location

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry for that @MarkSeemann, should I just copy and paste the text next time?

Comment: Why the port in callback url is 8090, not 8080 ? Could you share the links or blogs you are referring.

Comment: @JasonPan this was a typo.  I've updated the same and added some of my findings.

Comment: Hi @KyleBarnes, you are using linux or windows images ?

Comment: @JasonPan I'm using Linux images.

Comment: Could you try to use HTTPS ?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run the `Azure AD authentication` for a `ASP.NET Core MVC` application using Docker.

- While creating the template select the Authentication type as `Microsoft Identity platform`.
  [image]
- This enables to configure App registration from Visual Studio. No need to create and add the configurations manually.

[image]

The only difference I found in my Docker file is.

```cs
 ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
```

- Even I have tried with Debug.

Thanks @Jason Pan for the comment.

Yes,as mentioned by Jason Pan, instead of http, try with `https`.

- Even Iam able to run the application with the code which you have provided (`CookiePolicyOptions`).

***My  Default `Program.cs` file***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");    
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Docker Logs:***

```cs
2023-09-30 14:21:47       Now listening on: https://[::]:443
2023-09-30 14:21:47       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
2023-09-30 14:21:47       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-09-30 14:21:47       Hosting environment: Development
2023-09-30 14:21:55 info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
2023-09-30 14:21:55       Microsoft.IdentityModel Version: 6.32.0.0. Date 09/30/2023 08:51:55. PII logging is OFF. See https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII for details. 
2023-09-30 14:21:55       IDX10242: Security token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' has a valid signature.
2023-09-30 14:21:55 info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
2023-09-30 14:21:55       IDX10239: Lifetime of the token is valid.
2023-09-30 14:21:55 info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
2023-09-30 14:21:55       IDX10234: Audience Validated.Audience: '********'
2023-09-30 14:21:55 info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
2023-09-30 14:21:55       IDX10245: Creating claims identity from the validated token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
```

Refer the [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72010688/19648279) which address the same type of issue in older version.